# UITableViewController and detecting touches

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and want to detect touches.

Basically, I want the user to be able to hold down a touch for 3 seconds, when they let go I want to pop up a small view with a few options for the table.

I've tried this...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 self.lastTouch = [event timestamp];
 NSLog(@"TLC.touchesBegan:touchBeginEndInterval %f", self.lastTouch);
}  

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 NSTimeInterval touchBeginEndInterval = [event timestamp] - self.lastTouch
 NSLog(@"TLC.touchesEnded:touchBeginEndInterval %f %f", self.lastTouch, touchBeginEndInterval);
}
```

And it isn't picking up my touches at all...

Any ideas about the best way to implement this?

Comment: did you fix this issue? If so let me know the solution. Even I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

TableViews have sort of a "touch" delegate method. Implement this method for your tableView delegate:

```
// What happens when a row is touched
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

You shouldn't make them press for 3 seconds... just use the standard.

Comment: I'm already using that for other things.

I want them to hold down for a few seconds before I pop up another view.  

I thought about using the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method but wanted to leave that as Delete (which it currently is).

Any other ideas?

Comment: You should use the little blue button inside the tableViewCell. That is sort of the standard way to have more interaction with the cell. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure.jpg. This button is listed in the HIG: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SystemProvided/SystemProvided.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code comes from your `UITableViewController` subclass ... `UIViewController`s don't receive methods like `touchesBegan:withEvent`. Only `UIResponder`s like `UIView` an its subclasses like `UITableView` do. So you are trying to get the touches in the wrong place.

What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to respond to touches in the `UITableView` or in a `UITableViewCell`? In case of the latter, you can deal with the touches in your custom cell implementation.

Comment: UIViewController inherits from UIResponder, so can receive touches.

See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Now it's easy to accomplish with UILongPressGestureRecognizer:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandlerMethod:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
}
-(void)longPressHandlerMethod:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView]];
    ...
}
```